# MySQL query only returning first value in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I'm trying to convert usernames to their respective userid, but for some reason only the first item in the array is being converted. The rest are just nulls in the resulting array. I can enter the same name 3 times and still, only the first element of the array is converted.

Say I try to convert the following array to their userid's

```
$users = [1 => test1, 2 => test2, 3 => test3]
```

The resulting array is

```
$users = [1 => 1, 2 => , 3 => ]
```

This is the loop that looks up the userid

```
foreach($user_list as $user){
    array_push($user_id_list,$convert->userid_lookup($user));
}
```

here's the conversion function

```
function userid_lookup($username){
    echo $username //each name appears here
    $lookup = mysql_query("select userid from users where username = '$username' ");
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($lookup);
    echo $result['userid']; //only the first element's id appears
   return $result['userid'];
}
```

Why would only the first element be converted? I know each item is being processed because when I echo each item, they display.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: because you are using mysql_* functions

Comment: Ignoring the obvious fact that you shouldn't be using mysql_* functions, it is pretty obvious that there is no record with the username test2.

Comment: @Xnoise No, it's pretty obvious you're just being condescending. I can entere the same name 5 times and only the first will be converted.

Comment: well, I guess, the convert function in this case returns null. so there are very few places in which this can fail. One of them being that for that username there are no records in the database. Since the function as it appears to me receives the correct parameter, i guess you can draw the conclusion yourself. If i am missing something please forgive me. But it looks like that to me.

Comment: One more thing you can try to debug it: check if you have any errors reported by mysql_query. Then you can actually var_dump the result, just to check the actual type of the returned result. Also you can print the query and try to manually run it against database, see what results you get.

Comment: @xnoise - well, you were onto something. Turns out there was just whitespace at the beginning of the usernames. I used a jquery auto-select feature, and between each name it uses a comma and space.

Comment: I am happy it helped :). Usually in debugging issues you are trying to restrict the problem to a manageable section of the code. You did that very well, but didn't finish the analysis :). Cheers!

Comment: PS: i found myself some time ago in same situation. Since then, i pretty much use trim to get rid of all the empty spaces in the beginning/end of the variables. And as a second advice, switch to mysqli, and use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have to loop through your result to the next index.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you messed up your variable names.
setting up `$users` array but iterating `$user_list`
pushing results into `$user_id_list` but checking `$users` again.

Try to run the full code and debug it a little.

For the function itself - it looks good, though you have to properly format your string before inserting it into query.